# Pointers in C, integer pointer to character pointer

Tags: c, pointers

When I run this code:

```
int arr[3] = {2,3,4};
char *p;
p = (char*)arr;
printf("%d", *p);
p = p+1;
printf("%d", *p);
```

The output is 2 and 0. The second result is slightly confusing. Could someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Is this a homework? If so - tag it accordingly.

Comment: What happened when *you* ran this code? Reasoning: before posting a question here, it's always a good idea to show us what you've tried and what the result was.

Comment: The output was 2 and 0. the second result was slightly confusing. Hence the question. I'm a cardiac surgeon, who's trying to help my son with his homework. Unfortunately god has not made all of us a C expert.

Comment: Why you feel it as confusing? What answer you expected to get?

Comment: I guess i will not get an answer here,because i realised now, that the IT experts have no patience to answer questions which are simple, instead they can spend time in cross questioning. It doesnt reduce our self respect by answering simple questions. Thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: I just posted an answer, but your last comment makes me want to delete it. Don't make judgements about others.

Comment: @user1124236 we answer (and ask :D) lots and lots of simple questions on SO. However we especially like to answer questions which demonstrate some research effort of the asker.

Comment: @user1124236: people have no patience here with people who don't show effort when asking their questions. As you state in your comment, you did run the code, and what you are asking about is _why_ it prints these figures out. If you had phrased your question that way, you (probably) wouldn't have had such a negative response to your question.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments.

Comment: *Unfortunately god has not made all of us a C expert* hence it's a good idea to try elsewhere. C is used for low-level stuff like programming a pacemaker, imagine asking a question about on SO.

Comment: Many ppl are alive with a pacemaker. Life has less importance compared to programming i guess

Comment: @user1124236 take a look at the c programming language second edition

Comment: @bestsss Don't use the term "low-level" with non-programmers. They understand "low-level" as "low-importance" or "low-difficulty". I accidentally vexed several people in the past by using it :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's break this down:

```
int arr[3] = {2,3,4};
```

Creates an array of 3 integers. Assuming your system is 32bit little endian this is how it looks in memory:

```
02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00

char *p; p = (char*)arr;
```

`p` now points to `arr` but is a pointer to `char*`. In other words, `p` points to the `02`.

```
printf("%d", *p);
```

You are printing as an `int` the location referenced by `p`. So when you *dereference* `p` (by writing `*p`) you are accessing the `char` (since `p` is of type `char*`) referenced by `p`. Which is `02`.

```
p = p+1;
```

`p` now points to the `00` just after `02`, because `p` is `char*`. So when you add 1, it will move by `1 * sizeof(char) = 1 * 1 = 1` byte in memory.

```
printf("%d", *p);
```

You are printing as an `int` the location referenced by `p`. So when you *dereference* `p` (by writing `*p`) you are accessing the `char` (since `p` is of type `char*`) referenced by `p`. Which is `00`.

If you wanted to print `3` instead of `0` you have to change your pointer type to `int*` instead of `char*`, making the pointer move by `1 * sizeof(int) = 1 * 4 = 4` bytes in memory.

Comment: Let me also emphasize that while reading values of type `int` as if they were `char`s is legal, the exact result depends on the implementation. You could get another result when compiled elsewhere. @Cicada had to make assumptions about the platform in order to provide an answer.

Comment: assuming int is 32bit, it'd not matter if the platform is either 32 or 64bit (or even 16bit). on a flip note, pondering on endianness happened quite late for me, I used to assume only little endian type existed. coming from 6502, z80 and 8088 it was a surprise the numbers can be represented differently.

Answer (score 4):

The result you get will depend on the size of `int` on your implementation and its endianness.

Assuming 32bit ints, 8bit chars and a litte-endian environment (say x86), `arr` will be like this in memory:

```
<  arr[0]  > <  arr[1]  > <  arr[2] >
02 00 00 00  03 00 00 00  04 00 00 00
^  ^         ^
p  p+1 ...   p+4
```

If you take a char pointer to the start of that memory, and print out the first element, `2` should be output. If you increment that pointer, 0 will be output next. You'll need to increment it a few times more to 'see' 3.

Note that on a big-endian environment with the same type sizes, your program would have output two zeros, because the layout would have been:

```
<  arr[0]  > <  arr[1]  > <  arr[2] >
00 00 00 02  00 00 00 03  00 00 00 04
^  ^         ^
p  p+1 ...   p+4
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because of something called [endianness](http://www.intel.com/design/intarch/papers/endian.pdf).

When you create an array like `int arr[3] = {2, 3, 4};` it gets created in the memory as follows

```
Big endian:
    0   1   2     3      4   5   6      7     8   9  10     11 
  +---+---+---+--------+---+---+---+--------+---+---+---+--------+
  |   |   |   | ..0010 |   |   |   | ..0011 |   |   |   | ..0100 |
  +---+---+---+--------+---+---+---+--------+---+---+---+--------+

  <--       2       --><--       3        --><--        4      -->

Little endian:
       0     1   2    3    4   5   6      7     8       9  10   11 
  +--------+---+---+---+---------+---+---+---+--------+---+---+---+
  | ..0010 |   |   |   |  ..0011 |   |   |   | ..0100 |   |   |   |
  +--------+---+---+---+---------+---+---+---+--------+---+---+---+

  <--       2       --><--       3        --><--        4      -->
```

To understand more, you need to modify you program as follows:

```
int main(void)
{

    int arr[3] = {2, 3, 4};
    char *p = (char*) arr;  
    int i;
    int size = (int)sizeof(arr);

    for (i=0; i<size ; i++) {
        printf("%d", *p);
        p++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And, to check the endianness of you hardware, you can use the following function.

```
void endian(void)
{
        int i = 1;

        if (*(char *) &i == 1)
                printf("Little endian \n");
        else
                printf("Big endian \n");

        return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a paste that will let you understand the issue better: http://codepad.org/ClrrwjKY

As you can see, the value of the consecutive integers appear separated by three zeroes. This is because an integer is 4 bytes long, whereas a char is only 1 byte long. So when the int array is cast to char, you iterate over it byte by byte (or char by char), not by four bytes (int by int).

Answer (score 0):

Here as 'p' is a character pointer.. p+1 increments the current value of p only by 1.
As the array is integer, in order to access each values of the array one by one, you'll have to increment the character array by 2.
If the address of integer array is 1000
therefore,

```
  arr[0] is at 1000
  arr[1] is at 1002
  arr[2] is at 1004
```

and the value of arr is the address of arr[0];
so initially

```
 p=arr=1000
```

when p is incremented, p is 1001 whereas arr[1] is 1002

.. So in order to access all the values you'll have to increment the value of p twice each time..